# Build a dynamic where clause over multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

What I have is a `List<string> IndexFields` which contains a list of property names.

My issue is that I need to build a where clause based on the elements in the list.

So far I have;

```
var sitem = List1.Where(p => (p.GetType().GetProperty(IndexFields[0])
  .GetValue(p, null) as string) == "red").FirstOrDefault();
```

But that only allows me to specify a single property.  What I need is a builder that can build based on all the names in the `List<string> IndexFields` list.

Comment: There is something called PredicateBuilder which allows you to build dynamic where clauses, Google it.

Answer (score 6):

The most flexible way to create dynamic queries at runtime is by using the Expression API:

For example:-

```
var type = typeof(T);
var properties = IndexFields.Select(x => type.GetProperty(x));

// x
var paramter = Expression.Parameter(type);

// x.Foo, x.Bar, ...
var leftHandSides = properties.Select(
        x => Expression.Property(parameter, x));

// "Baz"
var rightHandSide = Expression.Constant(...);

// x.Foo == "Baz", x.Bar = "Baz", ...
var equalityExpressions = leftHandSides.Select(
        x => Expression.Equal(x, rightHandSide));

// x.Foo == "Baz" && x.Bar == "Baz" && ...
var aggregatedExpressions = equalityExpressions.Aggregate(
        (x, y) => Expression.AndAlso(x, y));

// x => x.Foo == "Baz" && x.Bar == "Baz" && ...
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,bool>>(
        aggregatedExpressions, parameter)

var item = List1.Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault();
```

A huge advantage of building your queries like this is that the resulting expression can still be e.g. translated into SQL for use with Entity Framework, wheras using reflection inside the body of your lambda is really limiting.

I really do recommend taking some time to really understand the expression framework before using it, though. If you can grok what's going on, it saves you a ton of time in the long run.

You can read more at e.g:-

- http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/37/dynamic-queries-in-entity-framework-using-expression-trees
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217539/net-expression-trees-tutorial

---

If you're looking for something quicker and dirtier, however, you can just go ahead and chain up those `Where` clauses inside a `foreach`:-

```
IEnumerable<T> query = List1;

foreach (var property in IndexFields)
{
  // The variable "property" gets hoisted out of local context
  // which messes you up if the query is being evaluated with
  // delayed execution.

  // If you're working in C# 6 though, you don't need to do this.
  var localProperty = property;

  query = query.Where(
    p => (p.GetType().GetProperty(localProperty)
                     .GetValue(p, null) as string) == "red");
}

var sitem = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Note: 'Where(Expression(Func(UMP, Boolean)))' is a method in 'IQueriable'. On 'Enumerable' you have 'Where(TSource)(IEnumerable(TSource), Func(TSource, Boolean))'. But the principal is correct, you just have to compile the expression into a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PredicateBuilder for this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<string>();
 if (aCondition)
 {
  predicate = predicate.And(s => s == "this");
 }

 if (bCondition)
 {
  predicate = predicate.And(s => s == "that");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this, worked for me in linqpad

```
void Main() {
    var listFields = new string[] { "Field1", "Field2" };
    var listValues = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    // prepare & show dummy data
    var listItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(aaIndex => new MyItem {
        Name = string.Format("item{0}", aaIndex),
        Field1 = string.Format("value{0}", aaIndex % 3),
        Field2 = string.Format("value{0}", aaIndex % 7)
    });
    listItems.Dump();
    // apply filtering
    var filtered = listItems.Where(aaItem => Enumerable.Range(0, listFields.Length).All(aaIndex => {
        var value1 = aaItem.GetType().GetProperty(listFields[aaIndex]).GetValue(aaItem, null);
        var value2 = listValues[aaIndex];
        if (value1 is IComparable) {
            return ((IComparable)value1).CompareTo(value2) == 0;
        }
        return Convert.ToString(value1) == Convert.ToString(value2);
    }));
    filtered.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class MyItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic linq library worked well for stuff like this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

It added overloads to take the different clauses as strings ie:

```
var query = List1.Where("Color1=""Red"" or Color2=""Red""");
```

In your case you could build the string from your index fields (probably in a loop but simplified here)

```
var query = List1.Where(IndexFields[0] + "=""Red"" or " IndexFields[1] + "=Red");
```

For use, [download the sample package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx), and then grab LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs and compile with your project.